# How to print .text from a label displayed in a tableView cell?

Tags: swift

I have a table view populated through a Nib.

Below is the .xib

[image]

And the .swift

```
import UIKit

class PeopleCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var peopleCellLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelTest: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }


    @IBAction func button(_ sender: UIButton) {

        labelTest.text = "Y"

    }


    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

In my PeopleDetailsController, how can I retrieve label.text ?

Below code only return "Label" (which is the default value) even if the button was pressed.

```
extension PeopleDetailsController: UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: K.cellIdentifierPeople, for: indexPath) as! PeopleCell
        print(cell.labelTest.text)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Calling `dequeueReusableCell` outside of `cellForRowAt` is pointless. As the label text is apparently predefined you should keep it in the data model, too. Then read the value from the model. You can signal the button action with a callback closure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were to do this, you’d retrieve the cell via [`cellForRow(at:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614983-cellforrow) (not to be confused with the delegate method `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`) which returns the cell associated with an indexPath (assuming that cell is visible):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let cell = tableView.cellForRowAt(at: indexPath) as? PeopleCell else {
        return
    }

    print(cell.labelTest.text)
}
```

But this pattern suggests that you’re storing model data within a view, which can be problematic. What if the row scrolled out of view and was discarded or reused? If you scroll it back into view, your string value has been lost.

Your button action handler should trigger the update of the model. Then `didSelectRowAt` would look up the value in the model, not in the cell.

Comment: i think there is no need for `if let` as the cell is for sure exists

Comment: @Sh_Khan this depends if there is only one Cell type

Comment: There’s that as well as the fact that `cellForRowAt` returns an optional, returning `nil` if the cell isn’t currently visible. In this context, that can’t really happen, but it’s important that OP differentiates between “dequeue a cell for row” and “retrieve the cell for a row if and only if it is currently visible.”

Comment: @Sh_Khan - His point is that the table might have more than one `UITableViewCell` subclass associated with it, thus force unwrapping to `PeopleCell` could be dangerous. The OP hasn’t shared `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` implementation, so you don’t know how many different types of cells there might be.